# Checking if element contains a number from 1 - 10

Tags: cypress

How do I check if an element contains a specific frame of numbers?

For example: I have an element where I'm trying to check if a number between 1 and 10 shows up. If that is the case, the test is successful. I'm not a dev and I'm quite new to all of this, so I'm apologizing if this is a typical newbie question.

I've read that there is something called regular expressions and that I can declare a specific set of numbers as a variable and put it into my code.

I don' have an example code, because I really don't know where to start.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show an example ? I am not sure to understand.

Comment: cy.get('data-testid=example]').contains(1 to 10)

Normally you can just check if the element contains one number. I want to test if it contains numbers 1 - 10, since they will be changing on the website.

Comment: So you mean *is* a number from 1 to 10 ? ("A10" contains "10".)

Comment: Yes exactly. Sorry for the miscommunication.

Comment: Try the regular expression /[1-9]|10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to the regular expression syntax is

```
cy.get('data-testid=example]').contains(/10|[1-9]/)
```

where the expression is between `/`,

- `|` means `or`
- `[1-9]` means any char from 1 to 9

You can play with expressions on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)